# How to design php file with many folders?

Tags: php, include, directory

I have a book site and want to create folders for every book.For example,

```
www.mydomain.com/book1  
www.mydomain.com/book2
www.mydomain.com/book3
```

Every book page will be same format and only book names and authors etc. will change by fetching data from database. So, creating an index.php file and copying it all book folders is  my idea. And index.php can be:

```
include "include_book_format.php";
```

So, format of book pages will be in **"include_book_format.php"**.
Is that a good design or is there any way to create it more efficiently? Thanks...

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? pure PHP?

Comment: You should check Codeigniter, it is very easy to learn and organize. It will suit your needs (for the URL issue)

Comment: _Is that a good design?_ - difficult to tell. What will you store in these folders - HTML documents? PDFs? You might consider using a content management system such as Wordpress, but there's not enough detail to go on. Or, consider a web framework of some kind or a template engine, so you can access layout facilities, caching, authentication etc without having to write it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You want create real folders? I don't think you need it.
You can use Rewrite Engine http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules